# pass a function into a filter angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm applying a filter on a controller which pulls data from a web API which works correctly. One thing i'm trying to achieve is when the filter searches the records and finds no data a function should be called from the controller.

```
    .controller('statement_ctrl',function($scope,$http,$ionicLoading,$ionicPopup,$cordovaToast,$location,$ionicModal,$filter){
        $scope.account_number=localStorage.getItem("account_number");
            ///alert if connection fails
            $scope.connect = function() {
            var alertPopup = $ionicPopup.alert({
            title: 'Error',
            template: '<p align="center">Problem Contacting Server</p>',
            });
            };


        $scope.nobill = function() {
                    var alertPopup = $ionicPopup.alert({
                    title: 'Error',
                    template: '<p align="center">Billing not Found</p>',
                    });
                    };

        $scope.state_request= function(){
        $ionicLoading.show({template: '<p>Processing Request</p><ion-spinner></ion-spinner>'});
        $http.post("http://myprojec/statement.php",{'id':$scope.account_number}).success
        (function(data){
        console.log(JSON.stringify(data));
        $scope.record=data;
        $scope.test='results';
        //console.log(JSON.stringify(results));
        {$ionicLoading.hide();}
            })

     $scope.from = $filter('date')($scope.sdate, "yyyy-MM-dd"+'T00:00:00')+'Z';
      $scope.to =  $filter('date')($scope.edate, "yyyy-MM-dd"+'T00:00:00')+'Z';


            }

    })
```

```
.filter('dateRange', function() {
    return function(records, from, to, nobill) {
      // return empty array if input not defined or not array
      if(!records || !angular.isArray(records)){
         return [];
      }
      var results = records.filter(function(record) {
         // run console log tests here...before the return
        return record.Date >= from && record.Date <= to;  
         console.log(test)     
      });
      if(results.length==0){
          nobill();
          }else{
              console.log('this is records in there')
              }
      console.log( 'Number of results:', results.length);
      return results;
    }
})
```

HTML

```
<form method="post" name="statement" id="statement">
<div class="list">
  <label class="item item-input">
    <span class="input-label">Search From</span>
    <input type="date" ng-model="sdate" required="required">
  </label>
  <label class="item item-input">
    <span class="input-label">Search To</span>
    <input type="date" ng-model="edate" required="required">
  </label>
</div>
</form>
</br>
<div align="center">
<p><button class="button button-positive" ng-disabled="statement.$invalid" ng-click="state_request()">
  <i class="icon ion-android-search icon"></i> Search
</button></p>
</div>
```

I want to call the nobill function from the controller to the filter if the lenght equals to zero. I tried and i got nobill is not a function.

Comment: I think you need a service that will do dateRange functionality  for you.  That way you can pass callback to the controller.

Comment: how do I do that?

Answer (score 0):

```
 var APP = angular.module('MYAPP');

APP
.factory('myDateSvc', [function() { // this is one way to define a service
    return {
        dateRange: function(records, from, to, nobill) {
            ... put your code here ...
            nobill();
        }
    }
}])
.controller('statement_ctrl', ['$scope', 'myDataSvc', function($scope, myDataSvc) {
    ... you code ...
    $scope.nobill = function() { ... };

    myDataSvc.dateRange(recordsVal, fromVal, toVal, $scope.nobill);
    ... more of you code ...
}]);
```

this is a basic skeleton to implement a service, inject it into a controller and call a service method from the controller passing a callback to $scope.nobill().  I have not tested it so you may will have to tweak it a bit, but it should work and it should give you a general idea.

Ia m afraid that is the simplest version I can come up with.  Hope this is helpful.